# Replace occurrence by ID using a condition - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (medications) where in some cases the medication name takes on two different types: `GENÉRICO` and `REFERÊNCIA`

Input:

```
medication_name        | type
ACETILCISTEINA           REFERÊNCIA
ACETILCISTEINA           GENÉRICO
ADDERA D                 GENÉRICO
ALLEGRA                  REFERÊNCIA
NOVALGINA                REFERÊNCIA
AMOXICILINA              GENÉRICO
```

Basically, I would like to make a query where every time a medication assumes these two types (GENÉRICO and REFERÊNCIA) the type occurrences are replaced by "INDEFINIDO".

Output:

```
medication_name        | type
ACETILCISTEINA           INDEFINIDO
ACETILCISTEINA           INDEFINIDO
ADDERA D                 GENÉRICO
ALLEGRA                  REFERÊNCIA
NOVALGINA                REFERÊNCIA
AMOXICILINA              GENÉRICO
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want the duplicates?

Comment: I will use DISTINCT later to drop duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to remove duplicates, the task is substantially easier than the same thing *with* removing duplicates.

```sql
SELECT medication_name, count(type)
FROM medications
GROUP BY medication_name HAVING count(type) > 1
```

Export result and with a text editor of your choice (text replacement) create an update statement for each medication.

So for example if you export this as CSV, delete the count column (or maybe - I don't remember if postgres let's you - you can leave away the counting column right from the beginning). Then use your text editor to regexp-replace every line with

Regexp: `^(.*)$`

`UPDATE medications SET type = 'INDEFINIDO' WHERE medication_name = $1`

where `$1` denotes the placeholder of your capturing group. Depending on your text editor, this might be `\1` or whatever syntax your editor uses.